# Java encodings for Japanese

Tags: java, encoding, internationalization, build-script

Our software has a script that creates different language JAR files, for Japanese we use the encoding SJIS in a call to native2asci.  This worked last time a Japanese build was attempted but now seems to only work in certain contexts.  For example in the following dialog the encoding seems to only work in the title bar:

[image]

Anyone have any idea about what might be causing this?  Could this problem be related to a change in Java?

Comment: Actually, the text in the title looks messed up as well... Could you elaborate more on how this localized text is stored and displayed?

Comment: The text at the top is supposed to look that way, I'm not quite sure why it the name of the app was translated that way but that's how it shows up in the localization files.

Comment: We have localization files stored in a filemaker database, we then export them to .tab files (tab separated text file), to handle the encoding the of the text file we use a program called NJStar communicator, which allows us to encode using SJIS, EUC-JIS or UTF-8.

Comment: so the general operation is: 1) create localizations in NJStar, with output in SJIS, then 2) convert to escaped unicode with `native2ascii`, right? If you are comfortable, I can check the input and output escaped unicode if you can provide both (for the above title and dialog text w/ button text).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you pass through native2ascii? Just to make sure, you're using native2ascii -encoding Shift_JIS, right? And you're passing text files or source files through native2ascii, right?

My only other idea is that after the text has been converted to \uXXXX format, the font you're using to display the dialog may not have all the Kanji and Kana. Explicitly set a font, and try that.

Comment: I am using the encoding Shift_JIS.  We pass through text files they are .tab files which are created using file maker.  We use a program called NJStar Communicator to handle the encoding when export files from filemaker.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking these 2 things:

1. Make absolutely sure that the `native2ascii` conversions are correct. You should do a round trip conversion with the `-reverse` flag, and make sure that your input and output are in sync.
2. Double-check that your fonts used can support Shift-JIS. Those blocks and symbols that appear in the dialog text and button text look like the characters might be OK, but the fonts might not support them.

An additional word of caution: If this application is intended for use on Windows, then you really should be using the `MS932` or `windows-31j` encoding. `SJIS` will work for all but a dozen or so symbols, but it turns out these symbols (like the full-width tilde) are actually used quite frequently in Japan.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this is to use UTF-8 or UTF-16 exclusively.  Kanji and Katakana demand special attention.

Comment: When I try UTF-8 it all shows up as strange asci characters, nothing Japanese looking at all.